# How does dependency walker know which functions in a module is used?

Tags: windows, algorithm, winapi, dll, dependencies

It can list the functions that's used among the exported functions.

How does it do the trick?

Comment: In fact in a static analysis it can't necessarily list all the functions that could be used. It doesn't reach those loaded explicitly with `GetProcAddress`. It only lists those that are linked implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that every Windows module (both executables and libraries) contains an *import table* that lists all of the other modules that it depends on. This table is built by the linker and is used by the operating system internally to determine the dependencies of the module and load the appropriate libraries.

So all that Dependency Walker has to do is recurse through all of those modules (figuratively, "walking" through them), building a list of the modules specified in their respective import tables.

It does *not* display all of the run-time dependencies (such as those loaded with the `GetProcAddress` function), as those are not listed in the import table. It only shows the load-time (or static) dependencies.

You can find more information about how Dependency Walker works [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_module_tree_view.htm) and [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/dependency_types.htm).